# How to test if result of a command contains a string in fish shell?

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion, fish

I'm trying to write a brief function to allow me to toggle wemo lights on and off from the command line. Basically I have a command that if i type `wemo status` will return either `Switch: Lights 1` if the lights are on or 0 if they are off. I'd like to write a fish function that essentially lets me toggle them:

```
function lights --description 'Toggle lights'
    if contains (wemo status) "Lights 1"
        wemo switch "Lights" off
    else
        wemo switch "Lights" on
    end
end
```

Though this doesn't work. I'm thinking that the parens probably do a textual replacement? Anyone know how I can test if a string contains another string in Fish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up fixing this with the following:

```
# Toggle lights
function lights --description "Toggle Wemo Lights"
    set -l wemo (wemo status)
    switch $wemo
        case '*1'
            wemo switch "Lights" off
        case '*0'
            wemo switch "Lights" on
    end
end
```

Comment: As lead dev on fish, this is my recommendation. You can do away with the variable if you like: `switch (wemo status)`…

Answer (score 3):

`contains` seems to be to test if a list contains an element

```
set elems foo bar baz
contains bar $elems; and echo yep
```

Using command substitution, the list appears to be line-oriented:

```
contains "e f"   (printf "%s\n" "a b c" "d e f" "g h i"); and echo y; or echo n
contains "d e f" (printf "%s\n" "a b c" "d e f" "g h i"); and echo y; or echo n
```

```
n
y
```

Pattern matching the result using `switch` is a good choice.

Comment: Correct. The thing about `contains` is it does not handle wildcard pattern matching. `contains opt\* $list` will not work as expected. Also, good to remember not to forget your `--`, when checking symbols with prepended hyphens, e.g, `contains -- -opt $list`.