# Testing command substitution output in fish

Tags: fish

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489086/how-to-test-if-result-of-a-command-contains-a-string-in-fish-shell) about testing command substitution for a *particular* string.  I want to test if a command outputs *anything* in a single statement, i.e., the equivalent of:

```
if [[ -n "$(foo)" ]]
```

in bash.  Fish doesn't recognize `[[]]`, and

```
if [ -n "(foo)" ]  # No good, "(foo)" is literal.
if [ -n (foo) ] # Passes only if (foo) == "\n" because of test semantics.
```

Won't work meaning I have to

```
set check (foo)
if [ -n "$check ]
```

Is there a possibility I've missed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
if count (foo) > /dev/null
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you think this would be more or less expensive than `if  [ (count (foo)) != 0 ]`?   I'm presuming the `> /dev/null` version saves a subshell...

Comment: @goldilocks About equal - fish isn't yet smart enough to elide the fork when outputting from a builtin to /dev/null, though it ought to be. If it were to elide the fork, the count command would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to use string substitution in Fish.

You can follow [#159 issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/159) to get more info about current solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In fish, we have to use `test` instead `[` or `[[`

```
if test -n (foo)
  echo not empty
end
```

Or, the equivalent of the bash `[[ -n $(foo) ]] && echo not empty` is

```
test -n (foo); and echo not empty
```

Comment: `[ ]` **is** `test`.  Try your example with, e.g. `if test -n (echo -n "")` -- You get "Not empty".  `test -n` (aka. `[ -n ]`) will only fail against `"\n"`.   A literally empty string (no output, as `echo -n ""`) will *pass*.